# ¿Como puedo hacer responsive de una imagen quede debajo de la otra?

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer que la imagen derecha pase debajo de la otra mediante responsive, lo que quiero tocar es `#foto3` y `#foto4` , he estado intentándolo pero no lo he conseguido y no entiendo lo que pasaba. 
Si alguien me pudiese ayudar lo agradecería mucho.
Saludos!

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #foto2{
    max-width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  #foto{
    max-width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  #foto4{
    margin-left: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #foto2{
    max-width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
  #foto{
    max-width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  } 
 
}

#foto3 {
  max-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#foto4{
  max-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="fotosoy">
  <img id="foto3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  <img id="foto4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Sin tener el **HTML** el **CSS** sirve de bien poco. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta añadiéndolo?

Comment: si ahora lo pongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, tienes un problema estructural con las **mediaqueries**. Cuando trabajamos con **mediaqueries** con `max-width` estás se han de colocar de mayor a menor para que funcionen correctamente (iría antes la de 600px que la de 400px, en tu caso las tienes al revés) y además han de estar colocadas debajo de las reglas **CSS** que no están dentro de ninguna **mediquerie** para que el efecto **cascada** de **CSS** pueda hacer su trabajo (de tener las **mediaqueries** encima del código normal, no conseguirías sobreescribir sus propiedades, incluso estando dentro del tamaño de dispositivo establecido por ellas) .

Una vez solucionado eso, lo que podrías hacer es llegados al tamaño de pantalla deseado, hacer que cada imagen ocupe el **100%** del ancho de su padre, para que de esta manera la una quede debajo de la otra, dejando de compartir "fila".

```css
#foto3 {
  max-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#foto4{
  max-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #foto3 {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  
  #foto4 {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fotosoy">
  <img id="foto3" src="https://www.affinity-petcare.com/advance/sites/default/files/field/image/diarrea_en_gatitos_1.jpg" />
  <img id="foto4" src="https://comunidad.retorn.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/09/gatitos/534533867.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ha funcionado!